# Dplyr non standard evaluation with function name passed as a string

Tags: r, function, dplyr, scoping, nse

While working with `dplyr` pipeline, I would like to pass a function to `mutate` using `NSE` with the function name being passed from a vector.

## Example

Given vector of two function names:

```
funs <- c("sum", "mean")
```

I would like to use first value to obtain sum:

```
require(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate_(res = funs[1](hp))
```

This results in an error:

```
Error in as.lazy_dots(list(...)) : attempt to apply non-function
```

### `do.call`

`do.call` based solution seems to generate some results for sum:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate_(res = do.call(funs[1], .))
```

but it fails when trying to use `mean`:

```
>> mtcars %>% 
+   group_by(cyl) %>% 
+   mutate_(res = do.call(funs[2], .))
Error in mean.default(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4,  : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I'm guessing that it simply makes no sense in the way it is applied here. Hence my question: *how to use [nse](/questions/tagged/nse) in `dplyr` so the function can be passed as a string from a vector?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `get` and `get` extracts the values of a single string. Here, it is a function, so it returns the function itself.

```
mtcars %>% 
     group_by(cyl) %>% 
     mutate(res= get(funs[1])(hp))
```

For passing additional arguments

```
mtcars$hp[1] <- NA
mtcars %>%
      group_by(cyl) %>% 
      mutate(res= get(funs[1])(hp, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: As always, this is super useful. Thanks; would you care to add a brief explanation? Also, how would I pass arguments to this function, like `na.rm = TRUE`?

Comment: @Konrad I updated the post.  I didn't see your edit in your comment earlier

Comment: Just used `get()` to get around nse to pass a function name to `by_row` using a string in `purrr` (actually `purrrlyr`).  This is an under-documented solution and VERY helpful!!  (Somebody, e.g., me, ought to submit a push request/documentation update).

Comment: @D.Woods  Another option would be `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(res =  eval(call(funs[1], hp)))`

Answer (score 2):

These both work using `mutate` rather than `mutate_`

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(res = do.call(funs[2], list(hp)))

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(res = match.fun(funs[2])(hp))
```

Also note that if we use [[2]] in place of [2] then these will work with both the character vector, `funs`, that appears in the question as well as `funs <- c(sum, mean)` .